# React Js and Spring boot faster xml jackson databin

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, findall

Hello when i try to get all values with this path : localhost:8080/aspsort/all
i get error :

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]

the method is :

```
@GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Rfpobject> getallRFP()
    {
        return rfprepo.findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of Iterable try changing it to List as return type .

and in rfprepo interface add this

```
@Override
List<Data> findAll();
```

example

```
@Autowired
RfpRepository rfprepo;


@GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Rfpobject> getallRFP()
    {
        return rfprepo.findAll();
    }
```

```
public interface RfpRepository  extends CrudRepository<Rfpobject, Long> {

    @Override
    List<Rfpobject> findAll();

}
```

let me know if this solved your issue.